# Right of a third party to financial disclosures arising out of a divorce

Tags: privacy, new-york-state, divorce

I am a creditor of a party who went through a divorce and I was told by someone who had been part of the proceedings that the debt to me was listed among the liabilities of the party in question.

Will it be possible for me to get access to that part of the financial disclosure that lists the money owed to me?

In other words, if I were to find out that the record was sealed, would I be able to ask the judge to unseal the part of the record that pertains to me?

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, if I were to find out that the record was sealed,
> would I be able to ask the judge to unseal the part of the record that
> pertains to me?

You could ask, but the answer would very likely be "no."

It is not uncommon for judges to require information be disclosed in one case subject to the restriction that it not be disclosed in another case. This is done to prevent information disclosed for one purpose from being used for strategic advantage in another case (often influencing what information is requested to be disclosed at all).

If the record is not sealed, you might be able to obtain it from the clerk of the court, although it is not uncommon for records containing personal financial information to not be made available as a public record to the general public, even when a case is not sealed.

In those cases, you could obtain the information from the debtor in discovery in your own lawsuit against the debtor, even though the court could not directly disclose it to you.